# Saving data from Spinners, RadioGroups ,EditText, across several activities to re-use

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, spinner, survey

Being very new to android I have limited experience despite having built several basic apps, so I would be grateful if you could structure any replies with this in mind.

I would like to: after a signup/login section, Collect user selections from spinners, radio buttons and text input over two or three Activities and in a fourth activity display the collected data so that it can be checked going back to make changes if need be.

When correct move on to a fifth activity where the data is structured and emailed to an email address given on the signup section. I have made the basic structure including Spinners with String arrays and have indeed made an app that works as required, passing data with extras to the next activity, however I would like to pass data to the final activity not just the next one in line. I do not really want to use a database if I can avoid it, but possibly so when all the data has been collected and reviewed, and having tried Sharedpreferences when things go wrong and the app crashes I struggle to find out why, so in an attempt to make things clearer I've stripped all that out back to basic structure leaving just working spinners, radiogroups and navigation buttons and here I am.

Being that the app structure I have left has 5 Activities and 5 class files I was hesitant to post the code as I was not sure that was the done thing, however I am willing to be guided on the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first activity, after collecting the data from the user, you can add them to your `Intent` using `Intent.putExtras(Bundle)`. This is an example using a username that the user entered in an `EditText`.

```
String username = myEditText.getText().toString();
Intent intent = new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
Bundle extras = new Bundle();
extras.putString("username",username);
intent.putExtras(extras);
startActivity(intent);
```

In the second activity, you can get the data from the extras in your `onCreate` like this:

```
Bundle extras = this.getIntent().getExtras();
String username = extras.getString("username");
```

When going to the third/fourth... activity, you can do the same steps to carry your data in the `Intent` you use to open the activity. First get the data from the extras, and then add them to the extras of the next intent.

You would probably want to make the variables global or because you will probably want to use them inside an `onClick` where they will not be accessible.

Comment: Thanks for that solution it was just what I wanted as it allows me an alternative to a database and Sharedpreferences  both of which I found in some circumstances to be over the top.